# Garbage disposal flange is leaking

Tags: sink, flange

I removed the flange, cleaned the surfaces and used fresh plumbers putty. It still leaked. I did it all again. It still leaks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include some pictures of exactly where it's leaking.  It could be leaking between the flange and disposal.

Comment: Yes, different brands mount to the sink differently. Help us help you by giving us a pic of the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The flange coming out of the disposer secures the pipe that attaches to the drain. There is supposed to be a rubber washer behind the flange that when the flange bolts are tightened seals the pipe connection from leaks.

disassemble once more and verify there is a washer behind the flange. If not get one and skip the putty.

If the leak is from the sink basket where the disposer attaches at the sink bottom it may be due to:

-not enough fresh putty. The putty should be rolled to a 3/8-1/2 inch diameter and overlapped where 2 pieces are used. More is better in this case.

-press the basket into place before tightening the screws underneath. You should see putty being forced from under the baskets flange in a continuous ring.

-the sink edge for the basket is bent or damaged. check for burrs or lippage with you finger.

-the basket screws aren't tight enough.

Comment: I think he is talking about the flange/strainer, where the unit mounts to the sink... but thank you for correctly using the term "disposer" as opposed to "disposal".

Comment: @Jimmy- yeah, maybe. thanks. I'll revise my answer.